# Using webpack mini-css-extract-plugin. The hash in img url by publicPath is different when import multiple css files

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, create-react-app, mini-css-extract-plugin

```js
// webpack
output: {
  publicPath: '/build/[hash]/'
}
```

```js
// some js
import './a.less'
import './b.less'
```

And then get the built css file:

```css
// main.a4bf602c.css
.page-a {
  background-image: url(/build/6c93287e0b98/imgs/bg-a.png);  // the hash is 6c93287e0b98
}
.page-b {
  background-image: url(/build/41ca954170df/imgs/bg-b.png);  // the hash is 41ca954170df
}
```

The hash in url in the built css file is different. How to let them to be same.
Thank you!